# How to combine values from two rows with the same index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have one dataframe with each two rows have equal "time" index, two "data" columns with possible equal values, value1 contains only positive numbers, value2 contains only negative values,  and one "type" column that differs one row from another:

```
time     type  value1 value2
01:26:00  A     1      -5
01:26:00  B     2      -6
01:28:35  A     3      -7
01:28:35  B     4      -8
```

I can plot bars for either type or combined bars plotted one over another (when I comment out line#1):

```
df = df.loc['type'] /line #1
df.plot(x='time', y=['value1', 'value2'], kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

What i need is to plot bars, with time on axis X, value1 of A side by side with value1 of B and opposite is value2 of A with value2 of B like this:

[image]

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand *"By far I achieve bar plot..."*, can you restate that please?

Comment: You have **two separate series**, as defined by the `type` column, so you need to pass that to the plot command. Or else manually `groupby('type)'` / iterate over the values of `type`. *"combine values from two rows with the same index"* you do not want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the seaborn [barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html#seaborn.barplot) function which provides the handy `hue` argument which makes it possible to display A and B side-by-side. In the following example, the `saturation` argument is used to differentiate value1 from value2:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd    # v 1.2.3
import seaborn as sns  # v 0.11.1

# Create sample dataset
data = """
time     type  value1 value2
01:26:00  A     1      -5
01:26:00  B     2      -6
01:28:35  A     3      -7
01:28:35  B     4      -8
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

# Create bar chart
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='time', y='value1', hue='type', saturation=1, zorder=2)
sns.barplot(data=df, x='time', y='value2', hue='type', saturation=0.6, zorder=2, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel('value1 and value2', labelpad=10)

# Format chart
ax.grid(axis='y', linewidth=0.5, zorder=1)
ax.axhline(color='black', linewidth=1, alpha=0.3)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', length=0)
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)

# Edit legend
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ntypes = df['type'].nunique()
ax.legend(handles[:ntypes], labels[:ntypes], loc=(1.03, 0.5), frameon=False);
```

[image: barplot]

Comment: Thank you, Patrick. That’s exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @user6836215 Happy to have been of help. I have edited the code a bit to make the plot look neater and more similar to the image you shared. The previous version is still accessible by clicking the [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67049944/revisions) button.